# Redirecting the lost password page request when using a custon login page

Tags: php, customization, filters, login, password

I have a custom login page and hence have setup the following redirects:

```
add_action('init', 'my_redirect_login_page');
add_action('wp_login_failed', 'my_custom_login_failed');
add_filter('authenticate', 'my_verify_user_pass', 1, 3);
add_action('wp_logout', 'my_logout_redirect');

function my_redirect_login_page()
{

    $login_page = site_url('/careers/login-register/');
    $page_viewed = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if ($page_viewed == 'wp-login.php' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
        wp_redirect($login_page);
        exit;
    }

}

function my_custom_login_failed()
{
    $uri = (isset($_POST['type']) and $_POST['type'] == 'admin-login') ? '/admin-login/' : '/careers/login-register/';
    $login_page = site_url($uri);
    wp_redirect($login_page . '?login=failed');
    exit;

}

function my_verify_user_pass($user, $username, $password)
{
    $uri = (isset($_POST['type']) and $_POST['type'] == 'admin-login') ? '/admin-login/' : '/careers/login-register/';
    $login_page = site_url($uri);
    if ($username == '' || $password == '') {
        wp_redirect($login_page . "?login=empty");
        exit;
    }
}
```

This works well, but I have recently discovered that it also redirects users to `/careers/login-register/?login=empty` when they request a new password.

I tried to fix this by adding:

```
add_filter('lostpassword redirect', 'my_lost_password_redirect');

function my_lost_password_redirect()
{
    $login_page = site_url();
    wp_redirect($login_page . '/?checkemail=confirm');
    exit();
}
```

...but it didn't work.

I tried playing around with the `priority` parameter on the `authenticate` filter but it didn't change anything.

**Edit:**

I actually found out a way to do it, such as:

```
function my_verify_user_pass($user, $username, $password) {

    $page_viewed = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $redirect = (strpos($page_viewed, '?checkemail=confirm') !== false) ? false : true;

    if ($redirect) {
        $uri = (isset($_POST['type']) and $_POST['type'] == 'admin-login') ? '/admin-login/' : '/careers/login-register/';
        $login_page = site_url($uri);
        if ($username == '' || $password == '') {
            wp_redirect($login_page . "?login=empty");
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

However not sure if there is a more standard way of achieving it or a way to not break it in the first place - is this possible?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to change the link url for lost password?

```
function my_lost_password_url() {
    return home_url('/lost-password');
}
add_filter('lostpassword_url', 'my_lost_password_url');
```

Comment: No, the lost password URL stays the same, but when they successfully request one they place they are redirected to shouldn't be changed from the default, which is `wp-login.php/?checkemail=confirm`. Also, please see updated question shortly.